# How to work with testcontainer which has been configured in spring boot yml file

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, testcontainers

I am trying to work with testcontainers MSSQLServerContainer but I can't find any information how to get instance MSSQLServerContainer which was configured in yml file.
I have configuration in yml file something like this

```
site-db:
    url: jdbc:tc:sqlserver://localhost:1111;DatabaseName=nameDb;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false?TC_INITSCRIPT=sql/create_tables.sql
    jdbc-url: jdbc:tc:sqlserver://localhost:1111;DatabaseName=nameDb;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false?TC_INITSCRIPT=sql/create_tables.sql
    driver-class-name: org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver
    jndiName: java:comp/env/jdbc/siteDb
    username: username
    password: password
```

When I run my test then the container starts too but I can get instance of this container.

if I try write this:

```
 @Rule
    private MSSQLServerContainer mssqlServerContainer = new MSSQLServerContainer();
```

then I get new container

Is there some way to get connection from testcontainer configured in yml file?

Answer (score 2):

When you are instantiating your container yourself as a field like this:

```
@Rule
private MSSQLServerContainer mssqlServerContainer = new MSSQLServerContainer();
```

you need to inject the `mssqlServerContainer.getJdbcUrl()` value into Spring using `@DynamicPropertySource`:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/DynamicPropertySource.html

However, since you are using the Testcontainers JDBC Driver Proxy approach by specifying `jdbc:tc:sqlserver://localhost:1111;DatabaseName=nameDb;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false?TC_INITSCRIPT=sql/create_tables.sql`, this is not necessary, since connecting to the JDBC-URL will automatically spawn a container.

If you need programmatic access to the container, I'd recommend to use the `@DynamicPropertySource` approach instead.